# How to unlock the table in mysql if user exit before completing the process?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to unlock a mysql table if a user close the page or browser while the data get saved into the DB.? Given below is what i am trying.

```
//to lock table
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES wo_booking WRITE");

//insert query
$pass_add=$objA->insert_fields(TABLEPREFIX.'booking',$fields,$values);

//to unlock table after write
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

If the table don't get unlocked, then how can next user data get saved?

Comment: Why are you locking tables yourself, are you not using InnoDB as your Engine? See this [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html)

Comment: If you want table level lock use myisam, row level use innodb.

Comment: If the connection of the client session got lost, it will be released .

Comment: thanks for the replies, but i would like to know how can i unlock the table if user close the page before unlock table occurs.

Comment: @frz3993, it will be released automatically?

Comment: Look under Rules for lock release, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @frz3993, thanks a lot.

Comment: Databases and their engines are already designed to lock and release the tables / rows as needed. So, generally speaking, there shouldn't be a need to worry oneself with this part of DB management. Taking these controls in own hands, at best, won't outperform the DB... and, at worst, could even be counter-productive. It's good to be aware of what happens in the background and how it is done. However, the only thing that I wish to stress upon is, aside from optimising the queries (and hence the tables and indexes), the application level programs shouldn't have to venture into anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the session that holds locks be expired, the table become unlock automatically. So it's better use transaction and its expiry, while I'm not sure you needs `lock tables` in `insert` query with `innodb` engine!

You can set `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to optimum value.

```
 set innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 88
```

As mentioned in MySQL Reference Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

> - A session can release its locks explicitly with UNLOCK TABLES.
> - If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while already holding locks, its existing locks are released implicitly before the new locks are granted.
> - If a session begins a transaction (for example, with START TRANSACTION), an implicit UNLOCK TABLES is performed, which causes existing locks to be released. (For additional information about the interaction between table locking and transactions, see Section 14.3.5.1, [“Interaction of Table Locking and Transactions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html).)